# A ECM QUESTION... FOR A 2016 KIA SORENTO

Tags: kia, code, electronic-control-module, sorento

How do i reprogram a used ECM if needs replaced?My boyfriend was hooking up stereo system and seems he fried my ECM??Inside lights and locks headlights all still work but will not start...

Comment: Unless you can afford a programing tool get it checked by a dealer.

Comment: Describe what happens when you try to start the car.

Comment: "My boyfriend was hooking up stereo system and seems he fried my ECM??" I doubt he did that.

Comment: Typing in all capital letters is perceived as SHOUTING. Please don't do that. You can edit your question (using the "edit" button below the question text) to change the format. It will be much easier to read, and more attractive...thus more likely to get good responses. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question,
For programming a new ecm on a hyundai with out dealer tool you can use most any j2534 pass through device (I prefer drewtech devices)along with Hyundai's aftermarket j2534 programming software found at (https://www.hyundaitechinfo.com/).

https://www.hyundaitechinfo.com/external/files/j2534_diagnostics_and_reprogramming/J2534_Reprogramming.pdf

I really doubt your ECM (engine control module) died, sounds more likely to be a blown acc/run fuse, bcm (body control module), or if equipped issue's with proximity key system. You probably should just take it to Hyundai or a qualified shop *to save time and money* before tossing parts at it.